# On form submit, it says - This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my first time I'm asking for help, after struggling for days now with this code. I've tried everything possible, but can't seem to make it work. Please help?

I have a webpage, lets say index.php , and inside it I include the footer.php file. Inside the footer.php I have a form which reference to the script callback.php

Inside the callback.php file, it successfully submit the form's info and inserts it into the database, but the problem comes in when you click the submit button.

It submits but then the webpage goes to the script's page, which is blank. `http://siteroot/scripts/callback.php`  and then says "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Here is my code:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if ($mysqli->query("INSERT into callback_tbl (namesurname, email, phone) VALUES ('$namesurname', '$email', '$phone')")) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Thank you, we will contact you as soon as possible'); 
</script>";

header( "Location: $actual_link" );
}
```

I even tried, but this also didn't work.

```
var currenturl = document.URL;
window.location.href = currenturl;
```

Please help!

Comment: Dont you try to reload the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` refers to the page itself (`callback.php`). Try this:

```
if ($mysqli->query("INSERT into callback_tbl (namesurname, email, phone) VALUES ('$namesurname', '$email', '$phone')")) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Thank you, we will contact you as soon as possible'); 
    window.history.back();
</script>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it didn't work completely for some strange reason but then I researched `window.history.back` and then I used `window.history.go(-1)` and that works 100%. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if this could be caused by the `header( "Location: $actual_link" );` and the `$actual_link` is making it redirect to the page it is already on.

Answer (score 0):

look here:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

here you get your script current address and here your redirect to current address

```
header( "Location: $actual_link" );
```

so you got loop :)